# " Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-16. There are no compatible JREs installed in the workspace"

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, buildpath

Eclipse for coding, SceneBuilder(JavaFX) for designing and MySQL for managing the database
I've been trying to build an OOP project for the university and I wanted to show my teacher what I've done( it wasn't finished). He tried helping me out but I got a new error everytime I compiled. He told me I have to switch from Eclipse to Eclipse EE in order to use JPA. That's what I've done, but there's something wrong with my compiler. I've seen a lot of videos, I've done the thing with Environment Variable with JAVA_HOME and stuff... I'm really desperate cause I will need to finish my project and I don't really know what to do, I'm new into computer science and the whole eclipse menu seems to be very overwhelming.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5ZW6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK8zo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilFuy.png)

Comment: Configure the Java JDKs/JREs that you want to use in your projects in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: @howlger I have selected jdk1.8.0_202, but I have the same error .. I have also an older version of jdk which is unchecked and I also have a jre1.8.0_191,which is also unchecked.

I've seen that when I try to run the program, that this appears in my console

" Unrecognized option: --module-path " should I enter something here ?

Comment: JDK 1.8 isn't compatible with JavaSE-16 in the sense that you can't simply use it in place of Java 16. You need an actual Java 16 JDK set up in your workspace's Installed JREs preference page.

Comment: According to your screenshots there is in the project, _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Libraries_ the node _JRE System Library [JavaSE-16]_, but in preferences _Java > Installed JREs_ you configured only a Java 8 JDK. That doesn't work. Do you want to use Java 8 (then correct your Java Build Path) or Java 16 (then you have to configure a Java 16 JDK in the preferences).